# Sitecore GetItem method's performance

Tags: c#, .net, performance, sitecore

I use the following code in Sitecore project:

```
Item item = database.GetItem(new ID("{id is here}"));
```

It takes more than 70 seconds to retrieve this item for first time. The second call and all others work much faster.
Is it possible to improve performance for the first call?

Comment: I've never seen `GetItem` call taking 70 seconds. Does it happen with 1 item only or any item in that project? Do you have any customizations like custom data provider or custom item resolver? You can try with a tool like `dotTrace` to find what's taking that long.

Comment: @MarekMusielak , unfortunately I do not know how to reproduce this issue manually. Clearing Sitecore's caches does not help to reproduce this issue. Probably it will take some time to understand if it happens with other items. Thank you for advice.

Comment: Does that item retrieval happen as part of the first calls to the website, so the entire cache needs to be rebuild first etc? Or is it on a "warm" site?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen , this item retrieval happens on the specific page of the site. So it is on "warm" site, I think.

Comment: @MarekMusielak , I use non-default(custom) database to retrieve the items. It seems like prefetching runs on first call and takes a lot of time. Do you know how to prefetch data on site running (as it works for standard databases)? I use the same prefetch configs as for web database.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption I can throw in is to blame initial item prefetch (configs in `\App_Config\Prefetch`). All the conditions are combined into one monster SQL query that could turn into [full table scan](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/277/index-scans-and-table-scans/) on large databases.

Since [query has server-side sorting](https://making-it-faster.blog/2020/01/01/case-study-database-optimization/), it will have to operate with huge dataset taking tons of time as in your case. `Initial prefetch` locks database operations so that all other have to wait for it to finish.

The cache cleanup operation has no influence on initial prefetch flag so that it is executed only once per database rain or shine.

Nevertheless, accurate conclusion can only be made by checking a [performance profile](https://github.com/mitikov/KeepSitecoreSimple/wiki/How-to-investigate-slowness-with-PerfView).